Vocabulary/Industry Term - Raw Video with unusable parts removed?
I'm new to video, so be gentle.
I have a lot of log(Apple, NLOG, GoPro) videos coming from various cameras, and the files are huge, so I'd like to cull them down to just the usable bits but still keep them in the original log format.  For an hour of video, maybe 5 minutes has something of value, and I'm thinking of disk space in future. These are essentially going to be B-roll clips for multiple projects.
Is there an industry term for these kinds of files?  They are original/raw but edited down, so not really.
Also, if anyone else does this...care to share your workflow around Media management?  I'm using DaVinci Resolve but would like to keep these media files organized/tagged/meta data independent of software or OS (MacOS).
I understand the Bin idea in DaVinci Resolve, but it seems to be a per/project thing. I want to do this across projects.

Can't answer for Resolve, but in Adobe Premiere, this process is called Consolidation - you trim the clips you want, copy the project to a new location, but only the trimmed parts of the video are copied. Be warned, as someone who has worked in video for a while, I never ever do this. Storage space is relatively cheap, the chances of disaster are quite high, especially because Premiere's Project Manager panel used to be quite unreliable and slow. Much better to keep everything imho.

Thanks.  I agree, but I just spent $600 to add more disk.  It hurts!
